# C++ auto_ptr and copy construction

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, auto-ptr

If I have a class

```
template <typename T>
struct C {
...

private:
  auto_ptr<T> ptr;
};
```

How do I define the copy constructor for  C:

It cannot be

```
template <typename T>
C<T>::C(const C& other)
```

because I want to if I copy the auto_ptr from other, I have changed other by removing
ownership.
Is it legal to define a copy constructor as

```
template <typename T>
C<T>::C(C& other) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent transfer of ownership and/or copying, you can define the copy constructor and assignment operator `private`, thereby forbidding users of your class from ever copying or assigning your object.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want to copy your class's state or transfer it?  If you want to copy it then you do it just like any other class with pointers in it:

```
template < typename T >
C<T>::C(C const& other) : ptr(new T(*other.ptr)) {} // or maybe other.ptr->clone()
```

If you actually want to transfer ownership of the pointer you could do it with a non-const "copy" constructor but I'd recommend you do something that's more obvious at the call site; something that tells people reading the code that ownership has transfered.

Comment: If he wants to transfer he doesn't need to do anything at all. The compiler provides the correct copy constructor automatically in that case - although i would recommend against that too.

Comment: Interesting.  I was sure you were wrong but it appears that the compiler will then create a non-const constructor for C automatically.  I'll have to look into the rules that make that happen.  At any rate, I still stand by my advice to use something more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "standard" copy constructor, but people do expect them to behave a certain way.  If your object is going to do any transferring of ownership on copy, then it's a bad idea to make a copy constructor that obscures this fact.  A better approach would be to create a method that makes this clear.  (You could call it CloneAndTransfer or something similar.)